# SQL Syntax error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: java, mysql, sql, user-interface

I'm following a YT tutorial on building a small gui to add students etc using a MySQL database. (Completely new)

I tried looking for any errors with mine and the video but can't seem to find the issue.

My code:

```
    Connection con1;
    PreparedStatement insert;
    
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        String name = txtname.getText();
        String cellNumber = txtmobile.getText();
        String course = txtcourse.getText();
        
        
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cput","root","");
            insert = con1.prepareStatement("insert into record(name,cell number,course)values(?,?,?)");
            insert.setString(1, name);
            insert.setString(2, cellNumber);
            insert.setString(3, course);
            insert.executeUpdate();
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record added successfully!");
        } 
        
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(registration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

I have a database set up with the same fields (name, cell number, course) in a table called record. When i try to add a record on the GUI I don't see it appear on the Database, instead I get this error.

Error:

> n 11, 2021 9:03:14 PM studentreg.registration jButton1ActionPerformed
> SEVERE: null
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
> 'number,course)values('John','123123123','Java')' at line 1

If anyone could let me know where im going wrong i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> `cell number`

No relation to java - in SQL you can't put spaces in identifiers like this. If your column really is named that, space and all, enclose identifiers (table names, column names, view names, index names, etcetera) in double quotes, but note that when you do this, it becomes case sensitive; check your DB table def, you may have to go with either `insert into record(name, "cell number", ...` or with `insert into record(name, "CELL NUMBER", ...)`.